# array based sumif in excel by formula

Tags: arrays, excel, sumifs

So I m trying to find some alternative to sumifs in excel where each condition needs to be checked in a 2D range instead of a 1D range.

For example, in the below table I want the sum of values in column V for rows where A12 ("IJ") is present in range A2:C8 (P), B12 ("NM") is present in the range D2:F8 (S) and C12 ("XX") is present in range G2:I8 (A)

[image]

I am trying to find a solution involving an array-based formula (without VBA).
Like for example in the below-given formulas,
`SUMPRODUCT((B2:B8'=A12)*J2:J8)` will give an array-based calculation as follows

```
SUMPRODUCT({TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE}*{22;79;45;67;43;72;52}) 
= SUMPRODUCT({22;0;45;0;0;72;0})
=139
```

It is easy when there is only one condition needs to be checked but like sumifs, I intend to check multiple conditions, but as soon as I add other conditions, the array becomes multidimensional and gives the wrong answer.

Example:

`SUMPRODUCT((A2:C8=A12)*(D2:F8=B12)*J2:J8)` breaks down to

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
{FALSE,TRUE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,TRUE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,TRUE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}*
{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;TRUE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;TRUE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}
*J2:J8)
```

in the background what is happening is (example for 3rd row)

```
SUMPRODUCT( ({FALSE, TRUE ,FALSE} * {TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}) * 45 )

= SUMPRODUCT({FALSE,FALSE,FALSE} *45 )

=0


SUMPRODUCT(({FALSE,TRUE ,FALSE} + {TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}) * 45 )

= SUMPRODUCT({TRUE,TRUE,FALSE} *45 )

= 90

#expected answer =45
```

Can someone help me understand where I am going wrong or what I am missing?

If there is any other way then suggestions are always welcome.

Please note this is a dummy data actual data is very big for each header (P,S,A) there are values in 10 columns respectively and the number of rows is also very large.

Comment: Array formulas for BIG DATA is asking for performance problems. That's not why your formula breaks, but just a heads up. VBA would be a MUCH better path for this.

Comment: In your example picture, the total you really want is 117 and not 88, right?

Comment: @Excel Hero, yes that I know but have restriction  for using VBA and for second, no in pic there are three conditions which is checked, i.e even ranges of A (G:I) is also checked for calculation.

Comment: The sum of V is 117 for these three conditions: P=IJ, S=NM, A=XX

Comment: @Excel Hero .. yes you are right .. sorry my bad.. wont be able to edit it at the moment .. but will do the correction

Comment: How many rows of data have you got? I could post an answer using the mmult way of doing it suitable for 10 columns, but it might be a bit slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
=SUMPRODUCT( ((A2:A8=A12)+(B2:B8=A12)+(C2:C8=A12)) * ((D2:D8=B12)+(E2:E8=B12)+(F2:F8=B12)) * ((G2:G8=C12)+(H2:H8=C12)+(I2:I8=C12)) * J2:J8 )
```

For SUMPRODUCT to work, the shape of the Boolean array needs to match the shape of the array you wish to conditionally sum.

`J2:J8` is seven rows tall by one column wide.

The above formula creates an array of 1s and 0s from your three criteria ranges and shapes it into seven rows tall by one column wide.

At that point, SUMPRODUCT can do it's normal thing because the criteria array matches the dimension of the sum array `J2:J8`.

Comment: Did this work for you? I'm about to go to bed. Please let me know.

Comment: That will work I know but as mentioned there are many headers (6-8) and each headers has 9-10 columns .. this formula will become very very big.

Comment: I hadalready that for demo it worked but for my actual issue it won't.. out of options  now